# Alternative to now() function in .tab extension

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to use now() function in .tab extension to dynamically find the **current system date**, but once closing the file, it got a hard-coded values.

Any alternative is highly appreciated.

Comment: And you've tried what?

Comment: i am working first time with .tab extenssion.. please excuse my little knowledge.. I have searched all over google but could find nothing :(

Comment: Got what working? I still don't see any code! From [link]http://pc.net/extensions/file/tab) it's similar to `.csv` which Excel should recognise and parse easily. I don't have a `.tab` file to test confirm what the link says.

Comment: edited the question, I need to add am expression to .tab file which works similar to now() in excel.. i.e which can dynamically find current system date and the expression should work even after closing and reopening the file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you get hard coded values when you save it because `.tab` is similar to `.csv`.

When you save it, everything in it is converted to values.

You can type formulae in but saving only sees the values.

If you want the `Now()` formula to stick you will have to save in an `.xls*` format.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but a there are a lot of tab files and the existing framework works with tab files only. I was just looking at any alternative or workaround which may fulfill my requirement in tab files.